# can't start rabbitmq-server after installation on windows

Tags: rabbitmq

I try to run this 'rabbitmq-server' command in my cmd but that give me this error ...

```
Configuring logger redirection
13:44:01.865 [warning] Using RABBITMQ_ADVANCED_CONFIG_FILE: c:/Users/saikat/AppData/Roaming/RabbitMQ/advanced.config
13:44:02.838 [error]

13:44:02.838 [error] BOOT FAILED
BOOT FAILED
13:44:02.838 [error] ===========
===========
13:44:02.838 [error] ERROR: distribution port 25672 in use by another node: rabbit@DESKTOP-1I7H1RC
ERROR: distribution port 25672 in use by another node: rabbit@DESKTOP-1I7H1RC
13:44:02.838 [error]

13:44:03.839 [error] Supervisor rabbit_prelaunch_sup had child prelaunch started with rabbit_prelaunch:run_prelaunch_first_phase() at undefined exit with reason {dist_port_already_used,25672,"rabbit","DESKTOP-1I7H1RC"} in context start_error
13:44:03.840 [error] CRASH REPORT Process <0.152.0> with 0 neighbours exited with reason: {{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,prelaunch,{dist_port_already_used,25672,"rabbit","DESKTOP-1I7H1RC"}}},{rabbit_prelaunch_app,start,[normal,[]]}} in application_master:init/4 line 138
{"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,"{application_start_failure,rabbitmq_prelaunch,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,prelaunch,{dist_port_already_used,25672,\"rabbit\",\"DESKTOP-1I7H1RC\"}}},{rabbit_prelaunch_app,start,[normal,[]]}}}"}
Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_start_failure,rabbitmq_prelaunch,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,prelaunch,{dist_port_already_used,25672,"rabbit","DESKTOP-1I7H1RC"}}},{r

Crash dump is being written to erl_crash.dump...done
```

Comment: as log reported, `ERROR: distribution port 25672 in use by another node: rabbit@DESKTOP-1I7H1RC`, you should declare another port or kill the process used 25672

Comment: how to kill the process used on port 25672?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No doubt you have already resolved this, but for anyone else this may help I had the same issue on Windows and managed to resolve it by doing the followed.

1. Open powershell **as admin** in  *\rabbitmq_server-3.8.9\sbin*
2. Stop the service by running: `.\rabbitmq-service.bat stop`
3. Start the service by running: `.\rabbitmq-server.bat`

Comment: tried ur commands but still seeing same error when stop command is run

Answer (score 2):

If you are on windows then go to Services

1. Search RabbitMq and Right click
2. Stop service
3. Open cmd as administrator
4. run cd C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.8.17\sbin
5. and then run `rabbitmq-server`

Answer (score 0):

For me what I did was killing the process of erl from the task manager and then running the command:

```
rabbitmq-server.bat
```